# geom_text() removing data after factor ordering

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a Gantt chart/ timeline using geom_segment (R novice).

this code:

```
timeline <- ggplot(db, aes(x=Discovery.date, y=Compound.name, label=Compound.name, colour=Compound.name))+
  geom_segment(aes(xend= End.Date, y=Compound.name, yend= Compound.name), size=5)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  geom_text(hjust = 'middle', nudge_x = 6, nudge_y= 0.11, colour="black")+
  labs(x= "Discovery Date",
       y= "Compound Name")+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none")+


timeline
```

returns this graph:
[wrong order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjUKU.png)

When I change the order to reflect the discovery date using this code:

```
db$Compound.name <- factor(db$Compound.name, levels = c("sarkomycin",
                                     "carzinophilin",
                                     "mitomycin C",
                                     "streptozocin",
                                     "chromomycin A3",
                                     "mithramycin",
                                     "bleomycin",
                                     "actinomycin D",
                                     "doxorubicin",
                                     "daunorubicin",
                                     "zinostatin",
                                     "aclarubicin",
                                     "peplomycin",
                                     "epirubicin HCl",
                                     "pirarubicin",
                                     "idarubicin HCl",
                                     "pentostatin",
                                     "zinostatin stimalamer",
                                     "valrubicin",
                                     "amrubicin HCl",
                                     "temsirolimus"))
```

db$Compound.name <- factor(db$Compound.name, levels=rev(levels(db$Compound.name)))

the result:
[correct order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vOVn.png)
this changes the order, but loses Compound.name= pirarubicin (y=7th from the top) and it becomes a grey segment at the top. The reason given:

> Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text)

Only the order of the data has changed and it's well within the xlim.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Sample code:

```html
Compound.name <- c("sarkomycin",
                   "carzinophilin",
                   "mitomycin C",
                   "streptozocin",
                   "chromomycin A3",
                   "mithramycin",
                   "bleomycin",
                   "actinomycin D",
                   "doxorubicin",
                   "daunorubicin",
                   "zinostatin",
                   "aclarubicin",
                   "peplomycin",
                   "epirubicin HCl",
                   "pirarubicin",
                   "idarubicin HCl",
                   "pentostatin",
                   "zinostatin stimalamer",
                   "valrubicin",
                   "amrubicin HCl",
                   "temsirolimus")
Discovery.date <- c("1954",
                 "1956",
                 "1958",
                 "1960",
                 "1961",
                 "1961",
                 "1962",
                 "1964",
                 "1972",
                 "1975",
                 "1976",
                 "1981",
                 "1981",
                 "1984",
                 "1988",
                 "1990",
                 "1992",
                 "1994",
                 "1999",
                 "2002",
                 "2007")

End.Date <- c("1965",
              "1970",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "1960",
              "2000",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "1985",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018",
              "2018")

df<- data.frame(Compound.name, Discovery.date, End.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `label` argument out of the `ggplot` aesthetic (`aes`) and into the `geom_text` aesthetic. (I also moved all your theme arguments into one block just to make it easier to read).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Discovery.date, y=Compound.name, colour=Compound.name))+  # OUT OF HERE
  geom_segment(aes(xend= End.Date, y=Compound.name, yend= Compound.name), size=5)+
  geom_text(aes(label=Compound.name), # INTO HERE
                hjust = 'middle', nudge_x = 6, nudge_y= 0.11, colour="black")+  
    labs(x= "Discovery Date", y= "Compound Name")+
    theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          legend.position="none",
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```